# Eclipse running very slow on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I am new on Ubuntu. I am developing one application using Eclipse (*Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819*). I have dual os on my pc. Window 8 as well as Ubuntu.

But now a days I am mostly using Ubuntu for my development work. But problem is my Eclipse is stuck on every copy/selection command for 20-30 seconds, and whole Os running very slow. I can't figure out where is the problem.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As easiest and fastest solution is reinstall your Eclipse.